# Using a homemade library of classes as functions in other class files

Tags: java, class, selenium, package

I am fairly new to Java so forgive me if this is a silly question, but believe me when I say I really cannot find a solid answer.

This is what I'm working with:
[image]

So I'm testing a program, and the easiest way to keep it maintained and updated is to create my own library of "buttons". Everything in the library are small functions like "enterValidCredentials" and "clickLoginButton".

So let's take a look at my test cases. In a perfect world I'd be able to just:

```
public class progressCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://mail.google.com/");
        enterValidCredentials;
        clickLoginButton;
    }       
}
```

enterValidCredentials and clickLoginButton exist in my library of classes. I know very well that that's not going to work as written above. What, literally, is the correct way to do this?

If it helps at all, my enterValidCredentials class looks like this:

```
public class loginPageButtons {
private WebDriver driver;
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

public class enterValidCredentials { // This class enters in a valid username and valid password on the login page.
    public void enterValidCredentials2() {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"text\"]")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"text\"]")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXX");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"password\"]")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"password\"]")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXX");
    }
}
```

All my other functions follow a relatively similar structure (depending on their function, of course).

Comment: you need to instansiate class and call it's public methods. (I guess firstly you should set `driver` variable)

Comment: Could you show me an example of code? @AlexanderStepchkov

Comment: Non-static methods @Gimby

Comment: You might want to take a look at the page object model. You can find a bunch of references/tutorials on the web. One such is on the Selenium site, https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a unit test to check single functionalities of your classes.

The most used library to create unit tests is [JUnit](http://junit.org/).

If you use an ide (like IntelliJ or Eclipse) running the test can be done with a simple command exactly as running a main method.

If you need to create mocks of your objects you can use a library like Mockito (but there are many other valid alternatives).

**Note:** A mock is an object that has the same interface as a complex object that is difficult to use in a test environment (for example a db connection, a file handler, a network handler).

Here is an example, I tried to imagine your code and a possible test. I assumed that clickLoginButton returns an integer just to show a possible assert statement.

Example:

```
@Test
public static void testCredentials() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://mail.google.com/");
    EnterValidCredentials enterValidCredentials = new EnterValidCredentials(); // Or create a mock if necessary
    // Set values if necessary
    int returnValue = enterValidCredentials.clickLoginButton();
    assertEquals(returnValue, 1);
}
```

Comment: Let's take the whole "testing" thing out of the question. I really just need to know the syntax for using a class as a function. We use JUnit, but our application is very large, with many many test cases, so creating this library of functions will help with maintenance of test cases (editing one function when all my xpaths get messed up, compared to editing 100 test cases).

Comment: What do you mean as "using a class as a function" ?

Comment: For example, we have a class called enterValidCredentials - when you run the code, it does exactly that (enters a username and password into some text fields). I want to be able to "call" this function in other classes (the test cases) so I don't have to repeatedly copy and paste the code. I really wish I could just (this doesn't work) type "enterValidCredentials" (thus treating it like a function) and my dreams would come true.

I want you to make my dreams come true.

Comment: The first block of code in the original post illustrates what I'd like to happen, I just literally have no idea how to make that happen. Like, if you ran that, the webdriver would go to google mail, enter my credentials and click the login button.

Comment: Simply create instance of the class that has your method (in your test function) and call this method. If creating a class is not so simple (because you need to create many additional objects, or you need to access a non running db or similar) create a mock of that object.

Comment: If it's not asking too much, could you show me an example of what that code would look like?